# "Ruby" UA string from Amazon

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, user-agent, bots

While sifting through Apache logs I have been seeing a high number of requests coming from EC2 (both east and west) IPs with the UA string "Ruby".  Considering they don't follow redirects and are in EC2 I suspect they are bots.  These are fairly new (within the last 3-4 months).

Speaking with friends at other companies they have seen this as well.

Is there a new "known" bot which is causing these requests?  They are pretty unique in the sense the UA string is just "Ruby".  This is more curiosity than anything.

Any feedback would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: It appears that requests from scripts written in ruby with use the default user agent "Ruby". Although they do often include the version. More information here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html

Comment: I've been seeing these too.  I'm blocking large chunks of Amazon's address space, but they still seem to show up with the same regularity